# Element margin covering whole width

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, margin

I want the logo and the links in my dropdown menu to be visible on the same line, without the logo's 'margin' (in orange) covering the links as displayed below.

1. This is a pure CSS dropdown menu using checkbox
2. I have attached the logo to the bottom white line. It is by design: when the menu drops down, the logo should follow.
3. Currently, the value that determines the max-height of the collapsed menu is the selector

   ```
   #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
     max-height: 65px;
   }
   ```

   The only reason it is at 65px is to actually illustrate the problem. `max-height` should be 35px

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shivashivashiva/cdh8tnvf/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to do.

I set the logo to float left and increased max-height of the nav from 65px to 70px and in menu .li add this css code vertical-align:top

Comment: clearly you haven't. does it not say max height should be 35px?